# Authentication, WsFederation & Cookie - User gets logged out after app restart

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, .net-core

I have the following

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("keys")).SetApplicationName("Base");

services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                    {
                        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddWsFederation(options =>
                    {
                        options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("Base");
                        options.CallbackPath = "/api/signin-wsfed";
                        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                        {
                            var list = context?.Request?.GetTypedHeaders()?.Accept;
                            if (list != null && list.Any(x => x.MediaType.Value.Contains("application/json")))
                            {
                                Log("OnRedirectToIdentityProvider", "Request for URL: '{URL}', Method: '{Method}', Status Code: '{StatusCode}', Old Status Code: '{OldStatusCode}'", context.Request.Path, context.Request.Method, 401, context?.Response?.StatusCode);
                                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                                context.HandleResponse();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Log("OnRedirectToIdentityProvider", "Request for URL: '{URL}', Method: '{Method}', Status Code: '{StatusCode}'", context?.Request?.Path, context?.Request?.Method, context?.Response?.StatusCode);
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            Log("OnAuthenticationFailed", "Auth Failed: '{Exception}'", context.Exception);

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };

                        options.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            Log("OnSecurityTokenValidated", "Validated for '{User}', Valid '{ValidFrom}' to '{ValidTo}'", context?.Principal?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn), context?.SecurityToken.ValidFrom, context?.SecurityToken.ValidTo);                      
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };

                        // options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
                        options.Wtrealm = Configuration.GetSection("WsFederation").GetValue<string>("Wtrealm");
                        options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetSection("WsFederation").GetValue<string>("MetadataAddress");
                        options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                        {
                            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (_, __, ___, ____) => true
                        };
                    })
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("Base");
                        options.SlidingExpiration = true;

                        // options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                        options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal += context =>
                        {
                            Log("OnValidatePrincipal", "Validate Cookie for: {User}. Token Issued Utc: '{IssuedUtc}', Token Expires Utc: '{ExpiresUtc}', Cookie Option Valid For: '{CookieOptionValidFor}', Allow Refresh: {AllowRefresh}, ShouldRenew: {ShouldRenew}, Cookie Valid For: '{CookieValidFor}'",
                                context.HttpContext.GetUsername(),
                                context.Properties.IssuedUtc, context.Properties.ExpiresUtc,
                                context.Options.ExpireTimeSpan, context.Properties.AllowRefresh, context.ShouldRenew, context?.Options?.Cookie?.Expiration);

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };

                        options.AccessDeniedPath = null;
                        options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                        {
                            Log("OnRedirectToAccessDenied", "Denied for user: '{User}', For path: '{Url}', Method: '{Method}'", context.HttpContext.GetUsername(), context.Request.Path, context.Request.Method);
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };

                        options.Events.OnSignedIn = context =>
                        {
                            var username = context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Upn);
                            using (LogContext.PushProperty("User", username))
                            {
                                Log("OnSignedIn", "User '{User}' logged in at: '{At}', Token Expires At: '{Expires}', Sliding Expiration: '{SlidingExpiration}', Cookie Lifetime: '{CookieLifetime}'", 
                                    username, 
                                    DateTimeOffset.Now, 
                                    context.Properties.ExpiresUtc, 
                                    context.Options.SlidingExpiration, 
                                    context.Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };

                        options.Events.OnSigningIn = context =>
                        {

                            context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                            context.CookieOptions.Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(8);

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        };
                    });
```

Every time the app is restarted/rebooted, the user gets redirected to the adfs endpoint, new token is receivede and a new cookie gets issued ...

I have a feeling that I must be missing something here ... but not sure what.

As see on all the log entries, I have tried alot ...

I have added the DataProtection part today ... it's not failing ... the app runs as before ... it's not issuering a new keyring in the "keys" directory, so I guess it's using that keyring to decrypt the data. But it's still not working ...

Now I'm out of ideas and need some help to understand the issue.

Any hint or ideas how to debug this is most welcome ...

If more information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a /#"()#/"(=!/#)("=#/ biiiiiip ...

Overriding the
`options.DataProtectionProvider` in both Cookie and WsFederation ... MY GOD.

After removing that part, now after every reboot it works. I know I use a directory under the app ... but when deploying a new version it's fine that the keys gets renewed and the user have to login again.